# How to read the logs of a different app?

Tags: android, root, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-8.0-oreo

My application `A` works with application `B` already on the playstore. 
Both applications read and write to the same database but application `B` keeps presenting problems when application `A` wants to work together and just shows the message:

> Unfortunately application `B` has stopped

I don't have access to application's `B` source code but I need to see what is happening.

Is it possible to read the logs on application `B`?

I have 2 rooted android devices, one with android-6.0-marshmallow and the other one with android-8.0-oreo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADB to view the logs on a rooted phone.

[This page](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27586/problems-accessing-message-logs-on-jelly-bean-with-alogcat/28853) has a fairly complete description of how to do that.

The short version.  Run a shell on the device using the adb shell command then navigate using the limited set of linux commands that are available.